# I think my app.html from Angular is not being injected

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a navbar I am trying to inject into a main page. I ran the page and checked F12 > Network which showed that the directive's templateURL (navbar.html) was either not called or not injected. There are no errors. Anyone have any idea what might be wrong with my code?

The directory structure is:

- landingpage.html
- js

  - controllers

    - NavController.js
  - directives

    - navappDirective.js
  - app.js
- templates

  - navbar.html

Below is the code:

landingpage.html

```
<html>
   <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!--<link href="../css/landingpage.css" rel="stylesheet">-->

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!--<script type="text/javascript">
        alert("this works");
    </script>-->

<body>
    <div>
        <navbar ></navbar>
    </div>
    <!-- Insert navbar-->

    <!-- Modules -->
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>

    <!-- Controllers -->
        <script src="js/controllers/NavController.js"></script>

    <!-- Directives -->
        <script src="js/directives/navappDirective.js"></script>

</body>
```

navappDirective.js

```
navapp.directive('navbar', function() {
  return { 
  restrict: 'E', 
  scope: { 

  }, 
  /*template: '<p>Hi</p>'*/
  templateUrl: 'templates/navbar.html' 
  }; 
});
```

navbar.html just has a paragraph currently for testing purposes.

Thanks

Comment: i think it is templateUrl path problem. try to put absolute path of template

Comment: Move meta tag to top of `index.html` file.

Comment: use '../templates/navbar.html'

Comment: I don't see `ng-app` anywhere in your HTML. How is Angular even being bootstrapped?

Comment: As Lex said, ng-app is missing. You register the directive to navapp, but where is ng-app="navapp"? I added you a code snippet:
http://codepen.io/marcbaur/pen/ZOxVyB

Answer (score 0):

`ng-app` is missing in landingpage.html

In you landingpage.html, please update it as below

```
 <body ng-app="myapp">
```

In app.js, you probably should have

```
angular.module('myapp',[]);
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Answer (score 0):

Thank You everyone!

I had ng-app called in navbar because that is where I was using the controller information and thought that would work.

The problem was solved with the following steps:

- Changed the templateURL to ../../templates/navbar.html
- Called the ng-app directive on the landingpage.html This allows the page to call the app. The still have the ng-controller directive in navbar for encapsulation purposes.
- After the above steps I still got a cross referencing error since you cannot call a html file from a file system. So I ran a python server using python -m http.server (for Python 3) after cd'ing to the directory holding my project. Then I could run my project using localhost:8000/